# Unable to fill ComboBox with Sql server column using the MVVM design pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

*(I tried reading similar threads, but couldn't find one that made me figure this out (most do not take into account MVVM).)*

Struggling to fill my ComboBox with Sql server table column, using the MVVM design pattern.
This is my method, in the ViewModel (TripViewModel.cs):

```
public void FillComboBoxLicenseHolders() {

    try {

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString.connectionString)) {

            SqlDataAdapter sqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter();
            sqlDA.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select Foretaksnavn from tblLicenseHolder", sqlCon);
            sqlDA.Fill(ds);
        }

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = ds.Tables[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) {

            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr = dt.Rows[i];
            LicenseHolder licenseHolder = new LicenseHolder();
            licenseHolder.Foretaksnavn = dr["Foretaksnavn"].ToString();

            LicenseHolders.Add(licenseHolder);
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
    }
}
```

If I set a break-point, I can see that it does indeed get the first row of the column as intended.
But the ComboBox is not filled.

This is how I bind the ComboBox in the XAML:

```
<ComboBox Name="cbLicenseHolder" Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="204" Width="291"
          ItemsSource="{Binding LicenseHolders, Mode=TwoWay}"
          Loaded="{s:Action FillComboBoxLicenseHolders}"/>
```

My BindableCollection, which is Stylets (framework) equivalent of an ObservableCollection, is set up like this in the ViewModel:

```
private BindableCollection<LicenseHolder> _licenseHolders;
public BindableCollection<LicenseHolder> LicenseHolders {

    get => _licenseHolders;
    set => SetAndNotify(ref this._licenseHodlers, value);
}
```

and it's instantiated in the constructor:

```
LicenseHolders = new BindableCollection<LicenseHolder>();
```

Which makes me feel I am doing something superfluous here...

Thanks for reading, hopefully someone here will be able to correct my thinking.